# Shear Transformation in terms of other transformations (Computer Graphics)

Tags: graphics, transformation, homogenous-transformation, matrix-transform, transformation-matrix

I want to express the Shear transformation in terms of other transformations (Rotation and Scaling transformation).
I am looking for Proof, to show the Shear transformation in terms of rotation and scaling transformation.

I have tried it by solving like first rotation and then scaling and vice-versa with different angles and scaling factors, but not getting how to prove or express shear transformation in terms of rotation and scaling.